# Function within ModelManager can't be called

Tags: django, django-models

I can't seem to access a function within my model manager.

**models.py**

```
class ChargeManager(models.Manager):    
    def dorefundcharge(self, charge_id):
        print(charge_id)

class Charge(models.Model):    
    charge_id = models.CharField(max_length=120)    

    objects = ChargeManager()
```

**views.py**

```
charge_id = 1234
refund_of_charge = charge.dorefundcharge(charge_id)
```

**Error**

```
AttributeError at /accounts/profile/refundcharge/540/
'Charge' object has no attribute 'dorefundcharge'
```

Comment: `dorefundcharge` is a method of manager, you need to call it like `Charge.objects.dorefundcharge(charge_id)`

Comment: What is the point of this method? Why have you put it on the Manager rather than the Model?

Comment: I omiited all of the code for the derefundcharge method as it wasn't relant. It runs a stripe refund. The tutorial I was following put other methods in the manager, so I thought that I'd put this one there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to use:

```
Charge.objects.dorefundcharge(charge_id)
```

For more details, check [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) in Django's official documentation.